# Callback for Fragment transaction within activity

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, fragment

I am looking for a callback for fragment transaction on an Activity.

So, I have an activity in that i keep on  changing the fragment, i need a callback every time a fragment is added or removed from the Activity. is there any callback for that or need to create my own callback??

Thanks

Comment: `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`

Comment: obviously FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your only available callback is [OnBackStackChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html).

Comment: thanks 
Is there any callback for Fragment like ActivityLifecycleCallbacks -> FragmentLifecycleCallback?

Comment: No, there is not. I wish there was.